# Buddypress - activation link not sent to user's email address

Tags: wordpress, activation

I recently installed buddypress in my wordpress.
When a person registers on my website using registration form
a message appears saying that an activation link has been sent to the email address you provided, but user receives no email.

Please tell me to solve this.
is there any problem in wp_mail or do I need to config 
something in my hosting file manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , test the wp_mail function with the following code by creating wp-test.php in root folder.

```
include 'wp-load.php';

$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

After that if it's still not working , you need to install and configure [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) and setup the SMTP settings from your host.